# Hypothesis testing and critical regions

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared, log-likelihood

Suppose $X$ follows a chi-squared distribution with $r$ degrees of freedom, where $r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is unknown. Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample of $X$.

(i) Suppose we have the following hypotheses: $H_0: r = 1$ against $H_1: r > 1$. We take $n = 10$ samples and reject $H_0$ if $\sum_{i = 1}^{10} x_i \geq 18.31$. Find the significance level of this test.

(ii) Compute $K(2)$, where $K(r)$, $r \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ is the power function.

(iii) Find the best critical region for testing the hypotheses: $H_0: r = 1$ and $H_1: r = 2$ of the form $\{(x_1, ..., x_n) : \sum_{i = 1}^{n} ln(x_i) \geq c\}$ for some constant $c$. Hint: Use the Neyman-Pearson lemma.

This is what I did:

(i) Let $C = \{\sum_{i = 1}^{10} x_i: \sum_{i = 1}^{10} x_i \geq 18.31\}$ be the critical region. The sum $\sum_{i = 1}^{10} X_i$ is chi-squared with $10r$ degrees of freedom.

Taking $r = 1$, the significance level, $\alpha$, is

$$\alpha = P(X \in C) = P(\sum_{i = 1}^{10} X_i \geq 18.31) = \int_{18.31}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma (5) 2^{5}} x^{4} e^{-x/2} \,dx = 0.0499541$$

(ii) The power function is the probability that $X$ is in the critical region when the parameter, $r$ is some number. So

$$K(2) = P(X \in C | r = 2) = P(\sum_{i = 1}^{10} X_i \geq 18.31) = \int_{18.31}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma (20/2) 2^{20/2}} x^{20/2 - 1} e^{-x/2} \,dx = \int_{18.31}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma (10) 2^{10}} x^{9} e^{-x/2} \,dx = 0.567$$

(iii) By the Neyman-Pearson lemma

$$\frac{L(1)}{L(2)} = \frac{(2\pi)^{-n/2} \prod x_i^{-1/2} e^{\sum \frac{-x_i}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2^n} e^{\sum \frac{-x_i}{2}}} = \frac{2^{n/2} \prod x_i^{-1/2}}{\pi ^{n/2}} \leq k$$

Taking the natural log

$$\frac{n}{2}\ln(2) - \frac{n}{2}\ln(\pi) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \ln(x_i) \leq \ln(k)$$

This is equivalent to:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \ln(x_i) \geq n\ln(2) - n\ln(\pi) - 2\ln(k)$$

This is of the required form where the RHS of the inequality is $c$.

Is what I have done correct? I am not quite sure about parts (i) and (ii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not quite sure about parts (i) and (ii).

they are both correct! usually in Statistics these questions are not answered solving the integral but reading the result on the tables.

[image]

(i) the significance level $\alpha=5\%$ is written in the red circle. for (ii) the table is not detailed enough...we have 19.337 and not 18.31 thus the result is a little bit greater than 50%. With a calculator or, as you correctly did, solving the integral  you get the exact result of 56.70%